# Show results across many variables Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a series of 5 variables (From the same table). I would like a Query to show me participants who have a value in *at least one* of those variables. I.e., if all 5 variables are blank, do not show that participant. How can I go about doing this?

```
SELECT [Patient Information].MRN, [Patient Information].[MRI_Results(1)], [Patient Information].[MRI_Results(2)], [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(Base)], [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU1)], [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU2)], [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU3)]
FROM [Patient Information]
ORDER BY [Patient Information].[MRI_Results(1)] DESC , [Patient Information].[MRI_Results(2)] DESC , [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(Base)] DESC , [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU1)] DESC , [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU2)] DESC , [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU3)] DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple "WHERE" clause will do the trick.  You want to use the OR operator since as long as one has a value you want to keep the record.

Depending on what your values are, you might need to change the syntax (i.e. "Not IsNull()" instead of "Is Not Null"), so this may require some minor tweaking but should get you in the right direction.

```
SELECT [Patient Information].MRN, [Patient Information].[MRI_Results(1)],
       [Patient Information].[MRI_Results(2)], 
       [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(Base)], 
       [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU1)], 
       [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU2)], 
       [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU3)]
FROM [Patient Information]
WHERE [Patient Information].MRN IS NOT NULL
  OR [Patient Information].[MRI_Results(1)] IS NOT NULL
  OR [Patient Information].[MRI_Results(2)] IS NOT NULL
  OR [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(Base)] IS NOT NULL
  OR [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU1)] IS NOT NULL
  OR [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU2)] IS NOT NULL
  OR [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU3)] IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY [Patient Information].[MRI_Results(1)] DESC , 
         [Patient Information].[MRI_Results(2)] DESC , 
         [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(Base)] DESC , 
         [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU1)] DESC , 
         [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU2)] DESC , 
         [Patient Information].[Blood_Results(FU3)] DESC;
```

Comment: Perrrfect. Thank you :) I don't know how to write SQL code yet and I couldn't figure out how to implement the WHERE function in Access without writing code